# Calling templated type with variadic arguments as a member function

Tags: c++, templates

In this simple example, I am trying to call F func which is templated in the EventQueue. With variadic arguments.

```
class EventQueue {
 public:
  EventQueue(int size) {}
  void Dispatch() {}

  template <typename F, typename... Args>
  void Call(F func, Args... args) {
    func(args...);
  }

  void DispatchForever() {}
};

class Example{
    EventQueue eq;
    public:
    Example():eq(10){};
    void Parse(){
        // Do something useful
    }

    void TestRoutine(){

    eq.Call(this,&Example::Parse);
    }
};

int main(){
    Example example;
    example.TestRoutine();
   return 0; 
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GsPMPb)

I get this error:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'void EventQueue::Call(F, Args ...) [with F = Example*; Args = {void (Example::*)()}]':

<source>:25:33:   required from here

<source>:9:9: error: 'func' cannot be used as a function

    9 |     func(args...);

      |     ~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

I'm a bit dumbfounded about this, any help to some resources would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I guess the problem is at the call site.

Comment: Yksisarvinen you are right.

Comment: That `Call` function is not ideal in that it does not do perfect forwarding. You probably want `template <class F, class... Args> void Call (F func, Args &&... args) { func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }`.

Comment: @Darhuuk Even better might be `F&& func`.

Comment: @DanielLangr Yup, looked right over that :).

Answer (score 1):

Based on aswear posted by question author proper code can look like this:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    template <typename F, typename... Args>
    void Call(F&& func, Args&&...args) {
        std::invoke(std::forward<F>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void Parse()
    {
        std::cout << "Parse\n";
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sjo93W)

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was solved, it was due to a problem at the call site. Pointed out by @Yksisarvinen in the comments.

From

```
queue.Call(this, &Skipper::Parse);
```

Changed to

```
queue.Call([this]() { this->Parse(); });
```

Comment: answering your own question is fine, but the information you posted here was missing from the question. You should rather fix the question

Comment: and this answer is not a proper solution, but just workaround, by using lambda.

Comment: AFAIK, if you capture `this`, you can then write just `Parse();` in the lambda body.

Comment: @idclev463035818 should I rather post this workaround in the original question instead?

Comment: you should edit your question to include the missing information, then the second part of this could make an answer. Currently there is no way somebody else than you could have come up with this answer based on your question only. Hence it is also not very likely that the question will be of use for future readers in its current state

Comment: @idclev463035818 I edited the original question to include the compile-able example code.